# Create criteria that ignores specific character

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I would like to create criteria or add restriction to my existing criteria (i think it has to be criteria) that will ignore "-" when searching for data's.

E.g I'm searching for number "888" and I would like to get "8-8-8" too.

I have bean that contains my number field

**A.java**

```
@Data
public class A {
    [...]
    @Length(max = 16)
    @Column(length = 16)
    private String number; 
}
```

And here's my criteria

```
    public Pair<Long, List<A>> filter(CompoundFilter filter, CompoundSort sort, int start, int count) {
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class, "a_alias");
...
}
```

What should I add to criteria to achieve my goal?

My other idea is to create some hidden field (by hidden i mean the one that i wont use on UI, only fill with datas) that will hold "transformed" values and when filtering `number` i will filter on this field

Comment: That does not seem very efficient. Maybe a virtual column calculated from the number column which removes non-digits + index on it.

Comment: you are right but unfortunately i have to do it hard way

Answer (score 0):

try using `regex` ,the pattern would look like `"[0-9]-[0-9]- ... [0-9]"` , here instead of 0-9 build the pattern with your desired number. If i understood your question correctly then this could be an answer.

Comment: I know i can use regex, the question is how to attach it to field in criteria

Comment: i dont know that , Sorry.